# Treat special symbols as text during xsd validation

Tags: xml, tags, xsd

I have multiple XML files which I'd like to validate using XSD. Problem is that somebody designed tags like this:

```
<name> Teststring <120> test <25> </name>
```

I want the tags <120> and <25> to be treated as text during validation - is there such possibility using XSD without modifying XML?

Comment: "I have multiple XML files" - why do you refer to these as XML files when they are clearly nothing of the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid XML. Those "tags" aren't closed and tag names can't start with digits. Trying to cram invalid XML into an XML validator is attacking the problem from the wrong end. Fix the XML.

```
<name> Teststring &lt;120&gt; test &lt;25&gt; </name>
<name><![CDATA[ Teststring <120> test <25> ]]></name>
```

Answer (score 1):

use CDATA syntax

> <name><![CDATA[ TestString <120> test <25>]]> </name>